# How to achieve same results with PBKDF2WithHmacSha1 in JAVA and Swift

Tags: java, android, ios, swift, pbkdf2

I am trying to strengthen the user password with the PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 encryption to produce a randomized salt and hash. Having successfully accomplished this in JAVA and SWIFT, i produce two different results of different lengths. in Java i produce a hash that is about 44-48 characters long. In Swift i produce a hash that is 528 characters long.

I've tried following the advice from this post , [PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1 Java to Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42931574/pbkdf2withhmacsha1-java-to-swift-3), but still did not receive the desired length.

***JAVA CODE***

```
SecretKeyFactory key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    byte[] hashedPassword = key.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    DebugLog.logd("Tools","hashPassword tableau bytes = " + hashedPassword);            
    return toHex(hashedPassword).getBytes();
```

with toHex() method provided from the post above

```
private static String toHex(byte[] array) {
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, array);
String hex = bi.toString(16);
int paddingLength = (array.length * 2) - hex.length();
if(paddingLength > 0)
    return String.format("%0" + paddingLength + "d", 0) + hex;
else
    return hex;
```

}

***SWIFT 3 code***

```
let passwordArray: [UInt8] = Array(test.utf8)
let saltArray: [UInt8] = Array(salt.utf8)

let result = try! PKCS5.PBKDF2(password: passwordArray, salt: saltArray,       iterations: iter, keyLength: 192, variant: .sha1).calculate()
```

I am expecting to get a hash function of equal length. for test purposes i use the same salt in both cases to try and get the same results. either way with java ill get 44-48 characters long and with swift i get 528 characters long. is there anyway i can alter the swift code to get a resulting hash equal to that of javas result. any help would be appreciated

***side note:*** In the post above, the OP used key length of 192 while i am using a key length of 256. i have also tried to comment and ask a question on the original post, but i dont have enough reputation to do so. i need 50 and i have 3 ... lol